# How to use python web automation in termux (Android) ? (need Installation of web driver)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, termux

I installed selenium but I have difficulty in installation of chrome webdriver

Comment: Would be helpful to add what you've tried and what errors (if any) you are seeing.

Comment: How to install Chrome webdriver in termux Android? I tried from GitHub but have a lot errors.